# How to show different error message on button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could you please tell me  How to show different error message on button click ? Actually when `pattern` is not matched it should show `pattern is not matched` .Currently I am only able to show `required` message .here is my code

```
 <TextField
          inputRef={register({ required: true, pattern: /^[A-Za-z]+$/i })}
          label="First name"
          variant="outlined"
          name="firstName"
          required
          helperText={errors.firstName && "First name is required"}
          error={errors.firstName ? true : false}
        />
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-j39p0

[image]

Comment: You may need a total validation service / libs

Comment: how can you give me example

Comment: can you change codesandbox with some example

Comment: There are related libs, but if you want to do it by yourself, here is an [example](https://github.com/ibarapascal/access-catalog/blob/master/blog/summary-of-react-develop-practice/summary-events.md/#validation) of mine

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like [react-validation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-validation) package. Using it you will be able to reduce the amount of code you will need to write for your own validation, and also consider the corner cases.

You define your validation functions at first:

```
import validator from 'validator';
const required = (value) => {
  if (!value.toString().trim().length) {
    // We can return string or jsx as the 'error' prop for the validated Component
    return 'require';
  }
};

const email = (value) => {
  if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
    return `${value} is not a valid email.`
  }
};
...
```

And after that plug them into your form, wherever required:

```
export default class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return <Form>
            <h3>Login</h3>
            <div>
                <label>
                    Email*
                    <Input value='email@email.com' name='email' validations={[required, email]}/>
                </label>
            </div>
...
```

Check out their documentation. It is pretty widely used package and should be easy to implement.

Comment: can you please use in my example

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will match with your example
[Run it here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-ok6x8)
replace the regular expression with yours

```html
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { TextField, Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import { object, string } from "yup";

class Usernames extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { errorText: '', value: props.value }
  }
  onChange(event) {
    
    if (event.target.value.match(/[abc]/g)) {
      this.setState({ errorText: 'errr' })
    } else {
      this.setState({ errorText: 'Invalid format' })
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <TextField hintText="Firstname"
        floatingLabelText="Firstname"
        name="name"
        helperText={this.state.errorText ? this.state.errorText : ""}
        errorText= {this.state.errorText}
        onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
      />
    )
  }
}


const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Usernames />, rootElement);
```

Comment: please help in my example

Comment: updated https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-ok6x8